# Gillson font is displaying as Times new roman

Tags: libreoffice

In my application I am applying gill san font it is working in windows,but in Ubuntu it is displaying as Times new roman.I have Libre Office in my Ubuntu System.But Why it is not supporting Gill san Font?

Comment: Do you have the font installed in Ubuntu?

Comment: Evidently not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font in question doesn't come installed with libreoffice. To install the font, you can download it [Here](http://somethingdesign.net/2012/10/gill-sans-font-family/) or you can search for it .  Once you download the font, just click it, and when the windows open, click on install.  That's it.  Open Libreoffice and enjoy.

[image]

Comment: Ok thankyou so much for giving quick replay.Is there any other way to do this one?

Comment: You mean other way to install?

Comment: You can do it manually by dragging the font into a particular folder (read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts)

Comment: No without install fonts is it possible?

Comment: No, you can't view a font in LibreOffice without installing it. It SHOULD display the font as Times New Roman but SAY that it is Gill Sans in the Font drop-down but LibreOffice isn't perfect :P